# How to pass promise as a props?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I've passed fetchData as a prop to child component. But the onClick function on button won't work

Parent Component

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2";

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(URL);
    const data = JSON.stringify(
      [response.data.id, response.data.name, response.data.email],
      null
    );

    setUser(data);
  };
  var array = user.split(",");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Todo fetchData={fetchData} />
      <UserData array={array} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child Component Button

```
                          <button
                          className="fetch-button"
                          onClick={() => fetchData}
                        >
                          View User
                        </button>
```

Comment: Typo, you need to invoke `fetchData` when clicked, `onClick={() => fetchData}` should be `onClick={() => fetchData()}` or `onClick={fetchData}`. Voting to close a "Unreproducible, caused by typo".

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 <button onClick={fetchData}>
 </button>
```